# extract the kind of geographic area based on GPS coordinates

Tags: here-api

is there an HERE api that returns the kind of area (rural/urban/ etc) based on GPS coordinates? I could not find it but I have the feeling there must be

Answer (score 0):

You can get the area of geoocordinates using the tile id [ admin level in terms of HERE query ]. Then you can use these details to get the kind of the area but currently there are no apis to determine the kind of area. You can have a hint at this example provided by thsir demo site. https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3.1/admin_boundaries . I hope this answers your query.